# IOS Location Updates in background mode stops when I use safari or other apps

Tags: ios, swift

I have enabled location services under capabilities for background mode, everything works fine if I click the home button, I get the updates. I even get updates when using safari until I go on facebook or something, it just stops. The app hasn't crashed or anything and It doesn't consume much memory nor does it drain alot of power. My app has an NSTimer which only requires the location after every 30 seconds.

App Delegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        var manager = CLLocationManager()

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            return true
        }
```

Main View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MainViewController: UIViewController, SettingsViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageMenuView: UIView!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var lastTimestamp: NSDate!
    var timer : NSTimer?

    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        var _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        _locationManager.delegate = self
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers

        // Movement threshold for new events
        return _locationManager
    }()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30, target: self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.startLocationUpdates), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func startLocationUpdates() {
        // Here, the location manager will be lazily instantiated
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
extension MainViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        print("location \(reminderTime)")
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```

**Update:** 
This issue happens on the physical device, iphone 5c

Comment: Is this on the simulator or a physical device?

Comment: @ZGski on the simulator everything works fine, on the physical device I get this issue. It is an iphone 5c.

Comment: Are you using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization ` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization `?

Comment: @ZGski I'm using manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization(), I posted the code actually in the OP. :)

Comment: NSTimer won't fire in the background. Since you turn location updates off in didUpdateLocations you will stop receiving updates and they won't start again

Comment: @Paulw11 my entire logic here is flawed. I moved everything to the AppDelegate and I handle things in the Application did enter background.